# Error when attempting to run mariadb server on console background in raspberry pi

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I keep getting an error when attempting to run a mariadb server on my raspberry pi and not really sure how to proceed.

I started a terminal window and these are the steps I have to follow for my class, however I can't even get past sudo mysqld -console :(

```
Installation of mariadb and simple exercise of CRUD:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo mysqld –console (to start the DB in the background)
(on a different terminal) sudo mysql (to log in as root)
create user ‘john’@’localhost’ identified by ‘password’;
select host, user from mysql.user;
```

Error Message:

e2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1) starting

```
as process 19643 ...
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-05-25 12:49:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=45178,45178
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Malformed log record; set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore.
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dump from the start of the mini-transaction (LSN=45178) to 100 bytes after the record:
 len 106; hex 73733130312e69626400120500b20108b20f05b50400000004b50400000015c30804ffc30204ffc30604ffc30204ffc30604ffc30204ffc30e04ffc30204ffc30604ffc30204ff34050075013405003540120501b20105460500802e10ff350500802d01b200fe350500; asc ss101.ibd                                                              4  u 4  5@      F   .  5   -    5  ;
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Log scan aborted at LSN 51712
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is '–console').
2022-05-25 12:49:21 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: `-console` isn't required. I normally use `--verbose` when running on a console. Your InnoDB error is more concerning. If you haven't got any data there, you can reset with `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/* && mariadb-install-db --user mysql`.

Comment: Why are you starting the MySQL server by "mysqld" and not by systemd?